# Dispatcher servlet blocking the uploaded attachments

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc in our application. The application has a form which has certain fields including one field for uploading attachments. The form submits to a controller. The problem is - 
whenever I upload an attachment, it doesen't reaches the controller. I have debugged the code and till the flow reaches the last filter to be called, the file is there. But then the dispatcher servlet gets called and after that no attachment reaches the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multipartResolver into spring-servlet.xml

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

reference link https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-file-upload

Comment: Its already there: <bean id="multipartResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

  <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />

 </bean>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was the multipartResolver. If we have created the bean(in case of spring) for this, and then using dsRequest.getUploadedFiles(), we won't get the uploaded files because Multipart resolver has already resolved the multiparts in Dispatcher Servlet. So, please avoid using multipartResolver in this case.